# Overriding max.message.bytes configs for __consumer_offsets topics getting lost

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently we are overriding the max.message.bytes for __consumer_offsets topic using the alter command but what we notice in some cases the config override is getting lost and changed to back default value of 1MB. When is this likely to happen? Where does kafka store the override for config values for __consumer_offsets topic?

Command used for overriding the config
`./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \ --alter --topic __consumer_offsets \ --config max.message.bytes=5242880`

Expectation: Config to be retained forever